# pg_upgrade: "lc_collate values for database "postgres" do not match"

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, postgis, macos-sierra

I've just upgraded (using Homebrew) my postgreSql and postGis installations. I can no longer 'brew postgresql-upgrade-database' (as it's telling me that my data is 'error: already upgraded' from a previous attempt; it's not, since the attempt failed), and going the manual 'pg_upgrade' route is fine, until treating 'template1' database throws a

```
    lc_collate values for database "postgres" do not match:  old "C", new "en_US.UTF-8"
```

error. I did not create that 'template1' database, so it is expendable (if not somehow needed) if it somehow possible to override the string-match requirement. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are unclear about which database is affected: `postgres` or `template1`.

To use `pg_upgrade`, the new and old cluster must be installed with the same locale. So try

```bash
initdb --locale=C ...
```

to create the new cluster.

`template1` is an essential database – without it, `CREATE DATABASE` will have a problem. You should also retain the `postgres` administrative database.

If both databases have different locale, you need to create the new cluster in the same way, for example:

```
DROP DATABASE postgres;
CREATE DATABASE postgres
   LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'C'
   TEMPLATE template0;
```

Comment: sorry for that, I'll clarify the question.

Comment: This reversed the situation (for another database): now the postgres database is throwing "lc_ctype values for database "postgres" do not match:  old "UTF-8", new "C""

So if we initdb in 'C', the postgresql database is going to throw a 'mismatch' error, and if we do it in utf-8, the 'template1' (transitional) db is going to throw it.

Comment: PS: I even tried "initdb -locale=C <database path> -E utf-8"

Comment: How did you get the cluster into that state? See my extended answer.

Comment: By using Hombebrew... I let it 'do it all' for me.

I did try creating the db's (with the appropriate collation), but when I intitiated pg_update, it threw a 'database exists' error and choked.

Comment: Then drop the database that exists but shouldn't.

Answer (score 27):

Simply update the collation and ctype encodings :

`UPDATE pg_database SET datcollate='en_US.UTF-8', datctype='en_US.UTF-8' WHERE datname='postgres';`

Repeat this query for `template1` & `template0` as well — or if you only have those three databases you can just drop the `WHERE` clause.

Check with `\l`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thank you! Done for template1 as well and everything worked like a charm!

Comment: for centos7, there is no datctype UTF-8, you should use, for example, datctype='en_US.UTF-8'. 

Otherwise, you will ruin your server and will not be able to connect anymore!

Comment: How can I run a query when postgres failed to upgrade and doesn't start?

Comment: I did this and had serious index corruption after the upgrade. Postgres let me write conflicting rows into the db that violated unique index constraints, and then refused to let me edit those rows because they had violated index constraints. Lookups using corrupted indexes (on string values) failed to find anything, while lookup by pkey indexes (integer) worked.

Comment: Confirmed: I reset `datcollate` and `datctype` back to `'C'`, created a new cluster using `pg_createcluster --locale=C --encoding=UTF8 12 main`, ran `pg_upgrade` again, and this time everything worked fine. DO NOT CHANGE LOCALE USING THIS METHOD!

Comment: Thank you!  One query to handle it all -- `UPDATE pg_database SET datcollate='en_US.UTF-8', datctype='en_US.UTF-8' WHERE datname IN ('postgres', 'template1', 'template2');`